# Error with facebook activity in android studio

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-studio, android-facebook

I'm trying to develop basic facebook activty and The app will get username and display it in screen but I'm facing a kind of FATAL EXCEPTION: main error I have provided my complete set of codes starting with manifest file, class file, xml file and the Logcat error,your help is highly required

The below provided code is my **manifest** file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.world.trialwithmugaputhagam">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name=".MyApplicatioon"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity android:name=".MainFragment" />
</application>
```

The below code is the **class file** I have used.In below code I have also assigned *mTextDetails* but when I hover the cursor it say the value is not assigned

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

public class MainActivity extends Fragment {

private TextView mTextDetails;
private CallbackManager mcallbackManager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    mcallbackManager=CallbackManager.Factory.create();
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,container,false);
}


private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mcallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        if (profile != null){
            mTextDetails.setText("Welcome "+ profile.getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {

    }
};



@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton)    view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton. setReadPermissions("user_friends");
    loginButton. setFragment(this);
    loginButton.registerCallback(mcallbackManager, mcallback);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mcallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}}
```

The below code is my **XML** file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.world.trialwithmugaputhagam.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Welcome"
    android:id="@+id/text_details"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/login_button"/>

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/></RelativeLayout>
```

**Logcat** error Sorry about the wrong alignment.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.world.trialwithmugaputhagam/com.example.world.trialwithmugaputhagam.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.world.trialwithmugaputhagam.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.world.trialwithmugaputhagam.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you can not cast  Fragment to activity. try to extends FragmentActivity ,AppCompatActivity or Activity. Otherwise why you need fragment ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988502/android-facebook-get-null-profile/35989033#35989033

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are extending `MainActivity` from `Fragment`. Thus, your `MainActivity` is not actually an `Activity` but a `Fragment`. Extend it from `Activity` or subclasses of `Activity`.

Like this:

`MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity`

Edit 1: (Based on comments):

You haven't initialized `mTextDetails`;
try to do like this in `Activity`'s `onCreate`:

`mTextDetails = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);`

Comment: Yes I have tried it but it leaves me with error on onCreateView and onViewCreated saying "Cannot reolve method"

Comment: Yes, because those methods belongs to `Fragment` not `Activity`. Load the layout inside `onCreate` of the `Activity`.

Comment: I just removed the code which blinked with errors and the now the program executes successfully with **MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity** but still i am not able to fetch the facebook username

Comment: That's different problem, try to check this Facebook SDK. Or add the error log here.

Comment: when I hover above ** private TextView mTextDetails;** It shows **mTextDetails** is never assigned but I have assigned it in line 49

Comment: @Eggsy, look at the updated answer. Can you also upvote my answer?

Comment: sure once I get 15 reps I am new develop :)